# histogram displayed as a line: force the plot of 0 if no value found

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a `data.frame` referencing scientific papers on a specific subjects. *All these papers have been published between 1985 and 2015*.

The structure of my data.frame (`my_db`) is:

```
"Authors" , "Title"       , "Year"
"Doe, J." , "Hello world" , 1985
"Foo, B." , "Baz"         , 2013
...
```

I want to plot an histogram showing the count of entries per year. I also want the histogram to use one line, and not beams. Therefor, I plot my graph as:

```
ggplot(my_db, aes(Year)) + stat_bin(geom = "line", binwidth = 1, center = 1980)
```

I get following graph

[image]

The line starts at year `1985` (what is tho oldest entry I have). However, **I'd like the line to plot `0`s for years before 1985** (see red line), so that it is more obvious there are no data prior 1985. I've tried `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1980,2015))` : it changes the graph span, but the line remains the same...

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use `geom_density()` instead of `stat_bin()`??

Comment: @PavoDive `ggplot(my_db, aes(Year)) + geom_density(aes(window = "rectangular",from = 1980), stat = "count")` is indeed a great start, but the "binwidth" seems too wide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering PavoDive suggestion, following graph did the job:

```
ggplot(my_bd, aes(Year))  + geom_freqpoly(aes(y = ..count..),binwidth = 1, center = 1980) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1980,2015))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Good you solved your own problem. That's the way to go!